# Lazy evaluation in Haskell's do notation using the trace function

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I want to know why this "debug message 1" doesn't get printed in this snippet:

```
import Debug.Trace

main = do
    return (trace "debug message 1" ())
    trace "debug message 2" (return ())
```

The second "debug message 2" is printed out, but not "debug message 1". It seems that both expressions are the same.

I tried binding the "debug message 1" to a variable, and then using that variable in another place, it did in fact trigger the evaluation and print "debug message 1", but I still don't understand why this happens.

If I flip the order of the statements, it is still the same result:

```
import Debug.Trace

main = do
    trace "debug message 2" (return ())
    return (trace "debug message 1" ())
```

"debug message 1" is never printed (using runhaskell).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess would be because of "lazy evaluation".

Note that you don't return anything. In other words, the "return" is not been queried yet (well there is no return), nor is it useful. Inside the `return` statement, you are not in a "monadic" context. So there is no reason to evaluate it, you simply pass the "call-tree" as the result.

In other words, it remains on the "*call-tree*" until someone wants to pick it up.

For the second case it is trivial that the `trace` will be called. The monad is executed until it reaches a "`return`", and before that `return` is reached, all necessary actions are taken, including executing debug info if needed.

Example in `ghci`:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> import Debug.Trace
Prelude Debug.Trace> do return (trace "debug message 1" ())
Prelude Debug.Trace> do trace "debug message 2" (return ())
debug message 2
```

Same for `runhaskell`. If you write these two programs:

**`program1.hs`**:

```
import Debug.Trace

main = do return (trace "debug message 1" ())
```

**`program2.hs`**:

```
import Debug.Trace

main = do
    trace "debug message 2" (return ())
```

Then the console reads:

```
$ runhaskell program1.hs
$ runhaskell program2.hs
debug message 2
$
```

If you however write an `IO Bool` (thus with return value) and you later use that value, the trace will be executed, for instance:

```
testFun :: IO Bool
testFun = do
    trace "foo" $ return $ trace "Hello" True

main :: IO ()
main = do
    b <- testFun
    print b
```

This will result in:

```
$ runhaskell program3.hs
foo
Hello
True
$
```

If you however omit the `print b` and put `return ()` instead, Haskell has no interest in the what is returned and thus doesn't print the trace:

```
testFun :: IO Bool
testFun = do
    trace "foo" $ return $ trace "Hello" True

main :: IO ()
main = do
    b <- testFun
    return ()   --we ran `testFun` but are not interested in the result
```

The result is:

```
$ runhaskell program4.hs
foo
$
```

Comment: If I flip the order, the same thing happens though. `main = do trace "debug message 2" (return ()); return (trace "debug message 1" ())`

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: if I run this in `ghci`, for the second, it prints the debug message. The reason that it is not printed in this context is because it is placed after the return statement. If you however perform `do trace "debug message 2" (return ())`, it will print the debug message.

Comment: Run this with `runhaskell`.

Comment: To be clear, when I run it with `runhaskell` no matter the order of the statements in the main, the "debug message 1" is never printed.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: well `ghci` is more or less the `runhaskell` equivalent, but interactive. As you can see, the second debug message is printed. But evidently, you must not place it after a `return` statement.

Comment: Ok so what you're saying is that within the do context, the runtime will evaluate any function in order to get to a possible return. That's why it executes the trace function. But if I have a return just by itself, not assigned anything, it doesn't bother trying to execute the expression passed into return? But won't the runtime want to know what the end result of the main function is? And the last value in the main function is the expression inside the return that hasn't been evaluated! Maybe we can try desugaring the whole thing to make it clearer?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: tried it with `runhaskell`: as you can see, the output is the same.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: well only if you actually **do** something with the output. If you would write an `IO (Bool)` and then fetch the bool, it will execute the trace at fetch time.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: did some additional tests which seem to proof that it performs all tasks until the `return` is reached. The call-tree of the `return` is not evaluated unless you process that value.

Comment: Ok I get it, any expression that is returned has to be used, or else it won't be evaluated. And by used, that could mean putting it as a parameter to another function like `print`. Does this mean `return` is kind of special, since it seems to have a different semantic to say just using the trace function, because the trace function gets evaluated automatically?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: no the `trace` is not special: a trace is only evaluated if necessary. `trace "foo"` is necessary to reach the `return` statement (whether we use the value or not), but `trace "hello"` only needs to be executed while evaluating the the call-tree of the `return` statement. So haskell needs to reach `return` in order to move to the next line (`return ()` or `print b`), but doesn't evaluate the `return` unless you need it (for instance to print it).

Answer (score 7):

There is no special magic about `do` notation.

```
main = do
    return (trace "debug message 1" ())
    trace "debug message 2" (return ())
```

is just the same as

```
main = return (trace "debug message 1" ()) >>=
        \_ -> trace "debug message 2" (return ())
```

By one of the monad identity laws, `return a >>= f = f a`, so

```
main = (\_ -> trace "debug message 2" (return ()))
         (trace "debug message 1" ())
```

The function ignores its argument, so the argument is not evaluated; the expression reduces to

```
main = trace "debug message 2" (return ())
```

The first message is entirely gone, and you can see that the remaining `trace` is now the outermost application that must be reduced to evaluate `main`, so this message will be printed.

When you flipped the order, you got

```
main = do
    trace "debug message 2" (return ())
    return (trace "debug message 1" ())
```

This is the same as

```
main = trace "debug message 2" (return ()) >>=
         (\_ -> return (trace "debug message 1" ()))
```

The situation here is a bit more complicated. The first `trace` (message 2) is forced, because `>>=` for `IO` is strict in its left operand. Then `return ()` is executed, doing nothing. Its value is ignored, and the final action, `return (trace "debug message 1" ())` is executed. This also does nothing (`return` *never* does anything interesting). Since the end of the `main` action is the end of the program, this return value is never inspected, and thus never forced, so it is not evaluated. Some people think that `main` should be required to have the type `IO ()` to emphasize that its return value is never used. (I believe they are wrong about this, because programs that run forever should really have type `IO Void` or `IO a`, but that's a nitpick.)

Comment: You could add a reference to https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/modules.html where it says “When the program is executed, the computation main is performed, and its result (of type t) is discarded.”

Comment: Nice answer. So what is the type of main if it isn't (implied by your conclusion) IO ()?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, it can be `IO a` for any `a`. Whatever it is, that result is never demanded.