# Why is traceM not always giving an output in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have the following function which takes an `Expr` and outputs a `[Typing]` and I am just inserting a traceM to see the function's behavior on a particular expression. However, it is not printing as it should and I am wondering why.

Expressions look like this:

```
data Expr = Vi Int
          | Vb Bool
          | Vv Name
          | App Expr Expr
          | Lam Name Typ1 Expr
          deriving(Generic, Eq)
```

The example I am running on is this one:

```
(App (App (Lam "x" dyn (Lam "y" dyn (Vv "x"))) (Vv "f")) (App (Vv "f") (Vv "x")))
```

The code is here. I am not sure if all of it is relevant, but I am trying to print what happens when I go into the "App" case. So I used traceM to see what happens in this case.

```
infer :: Expr -> [Typing]
infer expr = evalState (go expr) 0 where

go = \case
    (Vi _) -> do
      return [([], CInt)]

    Vb _ -> do
      return [([], CBool)]

    (Vv x) -> do
      v <- fresh
      return [([(x, v)], v)]

    (Lam x _ f) -> do
      lst <- go f -- list of all possile typings
      forM lst $ \(gamma, ty_e) -> do
        case lookup x gamma of
          Just typ -> do
            let v = CArr typ ty_e
            return (filter (\a -> x /= fst a) gamma, v)
          Nothing -> do
            v <- fresh 
            return (gamma , (CArr v ty_e))

    (App m1 m2) -> do
      (m1list, m2list) <- liftM2 (,) (go m1) (go m2)
      traceM (show m2 ++  " - " ++ show m2list ++ " \n ")
      traceM (show m1 ++  " - " ++ show m1list)
      traceM (show "app " ++ show (App m1 m2))

      fmap concat . forM m1list $ \(lam_env, t) -> do
        case t of
          CArr t1 t2 -> do
            let (m2env, m2types) = unzip m2list
            u' <- pleaseUnifyList (get_conj_elts t1) m2types
            -- traceM (show "list" ++ show u')
            -- traceM (show "possible empty list" ++ show (lam_env .+. solsum m2env, t2) )
            return $ case u' of 
              Right u -> [ substituteTyping u (lam_env .+. solsum m2env, t2) ]
              Left _ -> []

          _ -> do
            fmap concat . forM m2list $ \(app_env, s2) -> do
              (t1, t2) <- liftM2 (,) fresh fresh
              solve_all [t !> (t1 .~> t2), s2 .< t1, s2 !~ t1] lam_env app_env t2
```

When I run this code, I get the following:

```
"app "(λx:*.λy:*.x) f 

λx:*.λy:*.x - [([],0 -> 1 -> 0)]
f - [([("f",2)],2)] 

"app "f x 

f - [([("f",3)],3)]
x - [([("x",4)],4)]
```

This code was supposed to print  "app ".. for every App constructor. There are three App constructors in this expression but it only prints twice. In particular, I am missing the outermost constructor. How is this possible?

EDIT

```
infer :: Expr -> [Typing]
infer expr = evalState (go expr) 0 where
  go = \case
    (Vi _) -> do
      return []

    Vb _ -> do
      return []

    (Vv x) -> do
      return []

    (Lam x f) -> do
        return []

    (App m1 m2) -> do
      (m1list, m2list) <- liftM2 (,) (go m1) (go m2)
      traceM (show m2 ++  " - " ++ show m2list ++ " \n ")
      traceM (show m1 ++  " - " ++ show m1list)
      traceM (show "app " ++ show (App m1 m2))
      return []
```

After removing most of the code and running the above code, none of the prints show up at all. In the grammar, `Lam Name Typ1 Expr` should be modified to `Lam Name Expr`.

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to reproduce it... what package are `fresh`,  `.~>`, `solsum`, `.+.`... from? Can you reduce the code a bit, or is this truly a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Providing compilable code would be a huge help.

Comment: Sure I'll do that and edit the question. Thank you!

Comment: I simplified the code. Is it reproducible for you?

Comment: Yes, with a little bit of work. But now it prints out "app" 3 times.

Comment: @Lana could it be that your console buffer simply doesn't flush early enough? How are you running this?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin We just found the issue on chat, it had to do with OP using the lazy version of State. I'll let them self-answer (or someone else), since reproducing it was tricky, and other factors might be at play.

Comment: I just tested it on the larger version of the code. Just had to add this import import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict
and it solved the problem. Maybe you should answer it since you came up with it?

Comment: I just found out that this (tracing not showing due to lazy evaluation) has been covered before: [Lazy evaluation in Haskell's do notation using the trace function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673546/lazy-evaluation-in-haskells-do-notation-using-the-trace-function)